# How do I use collocation() to store it as a list

Tags: python, list, nlp, nltk, collocation

I have to save the bigram collocations  as a list in a variable but unable to do it with collocation(). I need to later return the variable from a function.

Comment: Provide please some short, reproducible code example. It will be easier for all to help you then.

Comment: I am actually using  a=nltk.Text(tokenizedwords).collocations() but it ends up printing instead of getting stored in a as a list. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try `collocation_list()` instead, `collocations()` is printing as it was designed to.

```
a=nltk.Text(tokenizedwords).collocation_list()
```

Sources:

- https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.text.Text.collocation_list
- https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.text.Text.collocations